# Batch - Parent Folder of current File Folder

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

My file is inside a directory, like in this example:

```
\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt
```

If i use this code (*%%~dp*) i will get the parent folder of my file:

```
for /f %%B in ('dir /b /s /a %%A) do (
        SET dir3=%%~dpB
        echo !dir3!
)
```

> **Output**: \folder1\folder2\folder3\

But now i want one more level, i'd like to get the name of the folder2

> **Expected output**: folder2

**Question:** How can i get the parent of my parent folder?
Note: preferably, if possible, I would like to do it without having to browse the directories (cd commands)

Thanks

Comment: Please cut-and-paste code, don't retype it. Retyping causes errors. Windows uses **backslash** as a directory separator, not `/`. `for %%q in ("%%~dpB.") do echo %%~nxq` should get that data, treating the directoryname as a filename.

Comment: If `%%~dpB` is the full path (i.e. `\folder1\folder2\folder3\ `), then `for %%C in ("%%~dpB\..")` is _the parent_ folder (i.e. `\folder1\folder2\ `) and `for %%C in ("%%~dpB\..") do echo %%~nC` show just _the name_: `folder2`

Comment: A simple example: `for %%I in ("\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt") do for %%J in ("%%~dpI..") do echo %%~nxJ`. See the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for details about `..` and the directory separator ``\`` and how the Windows I/O functions handle file/folder strings with `/`. Note 1: A folder path can contain one or more `.` and so better reference a folder name always with `%%~nx` to get complete folder name. Note 2: The usage of `/` in file/folder names can result in wrong behavior.

Comment: For completeness add to the batch file once also `for %%I in ("\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt") do for %%J in ("%%~dpI.") do echo %%~nxJ` which outputs `folder3` and `for %%I in ("\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt") do for %%J in ("%%~dpI..\..") do echo %%~nxJ` which outputs `folder1` and run the batch file to see these outputs too.

Comment: BTW, your statement "**Output:** /folder1/folder2/folder3/", is untrue, and therefore misleading. In addition to Windows using backward slashes, as already mentioned, and `ET` presumably being a typo for `SET`, `%~dp` expands to a drive letter, and path, yet your reported output most cetainly does not include a drive letter at all!